Diffeomorphism that sends compact set onto compact set
Let $h : U \to U' $ be a diffeomorphism of an open subset of $R^n$ onto another,
which sends the compact $K ⊂ U$  onto $K' ⊂ U'$.
Can it imply that the derivatives of $h$ are bounded on a compact set $K$ ?
Can you please give me some hints .

If $h$ is a diffeo, then $\nabla h$ is continuous and continuous functions are bounded on compact sets.

@SeverinSchraven: That should be made an answer.

What is your definition of a diffeomorphism? The standard definition requires at least $C^1$-smoothness.

One does not need that $h$ is a diffeomorphism. It is enough that $h$ is $C^1$. In this case, we get that $\partial_j h$ is continuous (by definition) and therefore $\partial_j h$ is bounded on any compact set.
